# This is a good responsive design method?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

Good night,

I´m starting my first adventure in responsive design and I have some doubts.

I´m develloping a website that I want it adpats to the tablet, desktop and smartphone. After a lots of research and study of Media queries I started to develop, through the research I did I realized that trying to do one layout for each different resolution was a bit unthinkable because it would take too much time. So I tried to catch the largest number of possible resolutions, resolutions that are most used and then I used *Media queries* to make the adjustments.

**My process:**

@media screen and (min-width:769px) {} for desktop versions
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {} for tablet versions
And for smartphone I´m using a php class to detect if its a mobile and then I have a design for that device.

Do you think I'm doing a good approach or do you think that during my research and study I understood something wrong to be doing this method?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media queries are a fine approach but you may find that it's easier to still have a separate file that simply is included within the media query, and would probably be the main suggestion I would make to a beginner (however, as you feel more comfortable with them, it's worth taking a look at using SASS to enhance management of complex css).